# Cmake FetchContent not downloading dependencies

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake Fetch Content to manage dependencies.

I'm trying to import `jsoncpp` as a dependency suing Fetch Content mechanism but I'm unable to do so.

The dependency is not downloaded in project folder.

Root CMakeLists.txt

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.25)



# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("Test")

include(FetchContent) # once in the project to include the module

FetchContent_Declare(
    jsoncpp
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
    GIT_TAG        8190e06  #1.9.5
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(jsoncpp)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("Test")
```

Test CMakeList.txt

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Test, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeTarget "Test.cpp")

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMakeTarget PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

Comment: "The dependency is not downloaded in project folder." - Please, elaborate what exactly is wrong. The `FetchContent_Declare` function downloads the given project into some directory, and folowing `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` calls `add_subdirectory` for that download directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I run cmake the dependency is not getting downloaded. I can't find jsoncpp anywhere in my project. When I try to include the jsoncpp header it can't be found.

Comment: "I can't find jsoncpp anywhere in my project." - FetchContent downloads not into the source directory, but into the build directory. For use jsoncpp in your libraries/executables you need to link with `jsoncpp_static` target (alternative targets:  `jsoncpp_shared` and `jsoncpp_object`).